# Foreign Key constraint is incorrectly formed-MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I am trying to connect a table to two different tables in my databases. I am receiving the next error:

> Error Code: 1005. Can't create table `project`.`orders` (errno: 150
>   "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")   0.625 sec

the table to e connected is:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  ORDERS
(
ORDER_ID INT NOT NULL UNIQUE auto_increment,
PRICE INT NOT NULL,
ORDERED_DATA timestamp default now(),
clients_ID INT,
product_second_ID int,
PRIMARY KEY(ORDER_ID),
 INDEX `fk_orders_clients1_idx` (`clients_ID` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_orders_product_second1_idx` (`product_second_ID` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_orders_clients1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`clients_ID`)
    REFERENCES `schooldb`.`clients` (`ID`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_orders_product_second1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`product_second_ID`)
    REFERENCES `schooldb`.`product_second` (`ID`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

the other 2 tables that will be connected :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  Product_SECOND (
ID INT  NOT NULL unique auto_increment,
NUME CHAR(24) not NULL,
STOCK INT,
RESTOCKED  timestamp default now() on update now(),
ADDED timestamp default now(),
PRIMARY KEY(ID)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  CLIENTS
(
ID int NOT NULL unique auto_increment,
NUME CHAR(24) NOT NULL,
PRENUME CHAR(24)  NOT NULL,
EMAIL CHAR(24),
PASSWORD_user CHAR(10) NOT NULL,
PHONE INT,
ADDRESS CHAR(50) NOT NULL,
DATE_CREATE_ACCOUNT  timestamp default now(),
DATE_OF_LAST_ORDER timestamp default now() on update now(),
PRIMARY KEY(ID)
);
```

Comment: You have to create clients and product_second before orders (how else will mysql see them) otherwise syntaxs fine for me.

Comment: I have created them before trying to create the order table.Also, not sure if it is relevant or not but, I have created  the tables (all 3 of them )in a model then applied forward engineering to obtain the code.

Comment: Are your table engines all innodb?

Comment: Yes. I have tried explicitly  with <ENGINE = InnoDB> and the result was the same.

Comment: OK as I said I have no problem with the code (after the removal of database qualifier schooldb which I don't have) so I'm afraid you are going to have to go through the requirements specified in the docs https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html And what deveopment environment are you using(phpmyadmin,toad etc)?

Comment: I am using MySQL Workbench 6.0CE run with root@localhost. I think i figured out the problem, thank you! (I was using the tables on a different database, not schooldb)